# angularjs filter Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to use a custom filter in the ng-repeat but facing an error as below.

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
>   Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ngRepeatFinishFilter

Here's my HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in (sc.people|ngRepeatFinish)| filter:f">
```

Here's my Controller

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('MYAPP');

app.controller("SearchController", ["mainSearch", "$routeParams", "$scope", SearchController]);

app.filter('ngRepeatFinish', function ($timeout, $scope) {
    return function (data) {
        //var me = this;
        var flagProperty = '__finishedRendering__';
        if (!data[flagProperty]) {
            Object.defineProperty(
                data,
                flagProperty,
                { enumerable: false, configurable: true, writable: false, value: {} });
            $timeout(function () {
                delete data[flagProperty];
                $scope.setNRCGroupColor();
                //me.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
            }, 0, false);
        }
        return data;
    };
});

function SearchController(mainSearch, $routeParams, $scope) {
   //
}

}());
```

Comment: $scope is not injectable into filters. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injecting `$scope` in filters is giving you error, try using your scope like:

```
app.filter('ngRepeatFinish', function ($timeout) {
    return function (data, scope) {
        // scope here will give you all access to $scope
        // your other code
    };
});
```

Comment: Try to put a comment when you downvote. Dear @SenseLessCoder

Comment: Happy to help ! you should close the issue .